# how to get values of parent child checkboxes at servlet

Tags: javascript, html

I want values of all parent and respective childs checkboxes at servlet to store into database.  how to get values of parent child checkboxes at servlet
 please help.
I want values of all parent and respective childs checkboxes at servlet to store into database.  how to get values of parent child checkboxes at servlet
 please help.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<!-- <script type="text/javascript">

$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){

    // if is checked
    if($(this).is(':checked')){

        $(this).parents('li').each(function() {
            $(this).children('input').prop('checked', true);
        });

    } else {

        // uncheck all children
        $(this).parent().find('li input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);

    }


</script> -->
<body>
    <p>Application Form</p>
    <div class="registration">
        <form id="createForm" action="NewUserServlet" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email"
                required="required" /> 

            <input type="text" placeholder="password"
                name="password" required="required" />

            <input type="text"
                placeholder="Name" name="name" /><br /><br /> 

            <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile number" name="MobNo" />

             <select name="role">
                 <c:forEach items="${RoleList}" var="rolelist">
                 <option value="${rolelist.roleId}">${rolelist.role}</option>
                 </c:forEach>
             </select><br></br> 
                <h5>Select Departments:</h5>

     <ul>

              <c:forEach items="${DepList}" var="list1">
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="${list1.did}" name="depp">${list1.dname}<br />
                   <ul>
                        <c:forEach items="${BkTypeList}" var="list2">
                          <li>
                              <input type="checkbox" value="${list2.typeId}" name="bkTypes">${list2.typeName}<br />
                                 <ul>
                                     <c:forEach items="${OpTypeList}" var="list3">
                                        <li>
                                         <input type="checkbox" value="${list3.otypeId}" name="oTypes">${list3.otypeName}<br />
                                         </li>
                                     </c:forEach>
                                 </ul>
                          </li>
                       </c:forEach>
                   </ul>
               </li>
              </c:forEach>
     </ul>


            <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit"/>

        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the action of the form to the url you want to POST

Then in your server code you have to map that URL to  your Servlet (you do this in the web.xml or in the Servlet itself if you use tags). Then you implement the doPost method of your Servlet and access the checkboxes by their name:

```
request.getParameter('depp');
```

Everything in the form will be submitted and can be captured as shown above.

Comment: that i know ..but I want parent and their respective child checkbox values

Comment: I don't understand.. there are no "parent" and "children", you just have a request with parameters (all at the same level). If you want your data to be hierarchical you need to send something like a json or an old fashioned XML, but then you don't post the form, you do it (normally) via an AJAX request.